# Why my code doesnt execute after the subscribe(observables ) ?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, observable

I have 2 methods where I get 2 list (accepted users and favorite users), the first part of my code function well and return users accepted and favorite , but in the second part of my code I want to clean accepted user list if user is in favorite user list.

and my code in my component is the next :

```
    ionViewWillEnter() {
//FIRST
          this._cp.listContacts('accepted').subscribe((invitations: UserProfile[]) => {
                console.log("EN ACCEPTED");
                this.invitationsAccepted = invitations;
            }, error => {
                console.log(<any>error);
            })
            this._cp.listContacts('favorites').subscribe((invitations: UserProfile[]) => {
                console.log("EN FAV");
                this.favorites = invitations;
            }, error => {
                console.log(<any>error);
            })
    //SECOND
         console.log("LENG INVITATION ACCEPTED"+this.invitationsAccepted.length);
                console.log("LENG INVITATION Favorites"+this.favorites.length);

                this.invitationsAccepted = this.invitationsAccepted.filter(o1 => this.favorites.some(o2 => o1.id != o2.id));
                console.log("RESULT");
                console.log(this.invitationsAccepted)
    }
```

Sometimes it functions and sometines not, how can i force to execute the second part sequentially when finish the first part ?

I've tried to do it with forkjoin also:

```
         let listAccepted=this._cp.listContacts('accepted');
         let favorites=this._cp.listContacts('favorites');

         forkJoin([listAccepted,favorites]).subscribe(results=>{               
             this.invitationsAccepted=results[0];
             this.favorites=results[1];
             console.log(results[0]);
             console.log(results[1]);
             this.invitationsAccepted = this.invitationsAccepted.filter(o1 => this.favorites.some(o2 => o1.id != o2.id));
         },error=>{
             console.log(<any>error);
         })
```

The problem is that it functions well when listAccepted and favorites not have errors,in other words when it has data in both, because my backend return error when it doesnt have data .

I hope you can help me .

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should execute sequentially.

```
    ionViewWillEnter() {
    //FIRST
              this._cp.listContacts('accepted').subscribe((invitations: UserProfile[]) => {
                    console.log("EN ACCEPTED");
                    this.invitationsAccepted = invitations;

                    this._cp.listContacts('favorites').subscribe((invitations: UserProfile[]) => {
                       console.log("EN FAV");
                       this.favorites = invitations;

                       this.invitationsAccepted = this.invitationsAccepted.filter(o1 => this.favorites.some(o2 => o1.id != o2.id));
                       }, error => {
                         console.log(<any>error);
                       })
                }, error => {
                    console.log(<any>error);
                })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve your goal without nesting the service calls is this:

```
private acceptedReceived: boolean = false;
private favoritesReceived: boolean = false;
private favoritesError: boolean = false;

ionViewWillEnter() {
      //FIRST
      this._cp.listContacts('accepted').subscribe((invitations: UserProfile[]) => {
            console.log("EN ACCEPTED");
            this.invitationsAccepted = invitations;
            this.acceptedReceived = true;
            this.filterUsers();
      }, error => {
            console.log(<any>error);
      });

      this._cp.listContacts('favorites').subscribe((invitations: UserProfile[]) => {
            console.log("EN FAV");
            this.favorites = invitations;
            this.favoritesReceived = true;
            this.filterUsers();
      }, error => {
            console.log(<any>error);
            this.favoritesError = true;
            this.filterUsers();
      });  
}

private filterUsers(): void {
    if(this.acceptedReceived && (this.favoritesReceived || this.favoritesError)){
        //SECOND
        console.log("LENG INVITATION ACCEPTED"+this.invitationsAccepted.length);
        console.log("LENG INVITATION Favorites"+this.favorites.length);

        this.invitationsAccepted = this.invitationsAccepted.filter(o1 => this.favorites.some(o2 => o1.id != o2.id));

        console.log("RESULT");
        console.log(this.invitationsAccepted) 
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this code but it only works fine when, 2 subscribe return data, in my case when dont exist favorite users , as an example, it will return error and it doesnt function

Comment: Okay, in that case just use another boolean variable. I named it `favoritesError`.  Please, have a look at my edited example. You can do this for accepted too, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`subscribe` is asynchronous the two events may not give results one after another. try calling the `this._cp.listContacts('favorites')` inside success callback of `this._cp.listContacts('accepted')` like this you can be certain that `this.invitationsAccepted` value is set and in the success callback of `this._cp.listContacts('favorites')` you can filter the users as you wished.
like

```
this._cp.listContacts('accepted').subscribe((invitations: UserProfile[]) => {
                console.log("EN ACCEPTED");
                this.invitationsAccepted = invitations;
                this._cp.listContacts('favorites').subscribe((favs: UserProfile[]) => {
                console.log("EN FAV");
                this.favorites = favs;
                this.invitationsAccepted = this.invitationsAccepted.filter(o1 => this.favorites.some(o2 => o1.id != o2.id));
            }, err => {
                console.log(<any>err);
            })
            }, error => {
                console.log(<any>error);
            })
```